# NativeBase FooterTab returns error when using an Icon

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I used the Native Base [docs](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.9/components#footerTabs) as a base to create a FooterTab.

I receive the following error if I add an Icon element to a button: undefined is not an object (evaluation 'child.props.children.props.name') from FooterTab.js:114 (has since changed, now [line 142](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/Components/Widgets/FooterTab.js#L142)).

Below is the code I am using in my render function:

```
<Footer>
      <FooterTab>
          <Button active={this.state.detailsTab} onPress={() => this.toggleDetailsTab()}>
              Details
              <Icon name='ios-home' style={globalStyles.inspectionsItemIcon} />
          </Button>
          <Button active={this.state.inspectionTab} onPress={() => this.toggleInspectionTab()}>
              Inspection
          </Button>
          <Button active={this.state.insectsTab} onPress={() => this.toggleInsectsTab()}>
              Insects
          </Button>
          <Button active={this.state.radonTab} onPress={() => this.toggleRadonTab()}>
              Radon
          </Button>
      </FooterTab>
</Footer>
```

If I remove the Icon from the first button everything works well.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if your Icon component is imported from NativeBase:

```
import { Icon } from 'native-base';
```

FooterTab.js checks for NativeBase's Icon component at line 88.

If it is not one, then it will just load the 'name' property at line 142 which will result in error because there are 2 children ('Details' text and Icon component).

Comment: Solved, thank you so much!!! I was importing Icon like this: import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'. Switched it to your recommendation and it solved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome. If you just want to show the Icon component only, then importing the component from 'react-native-vector-icons' should be working fine in the FooterTab. Else, you will have to import it from NativeBase.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring the previous version of docs

Check [Footer Tab](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13/components#footerTabs) with the latest [docs](http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.5.13)

Also you can check [NativeBase KitchenSink](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink), which showcase NativeBase components.

Check [Footer Tab](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/blob/master/js/components/anatomy/index.js) in NativeBase KitchenSink